# Bloomberg data does not refresh while running vba

Tags: vba, excel, bloomberg

I am currently working on a VBA code that does the following:

1.Copies a ticker from one sheet to another (same workbook)

2. The sheet where the ticker is copied to should be refreshed and populated by bloomberg
3. That sheet is exported as a PDF
4. Do the same process while there are no more tickers in the first sheet.

I am having issues, because the code that I created does not seem to work properly with the Bloomberg. The iteration works well, so does the export to PDF part. However, while the loop is going, there is not enough time for Bloomberg to refresh the sheet I want to export. I end up with three sheets out of four with N/As instead of the correct data.

Here is what I have so far

```
Public Sub RefreshStaticLinks()
    Call Worksheets("M").UsedRange.Select
    Call Application.Run("RefreshCurrentSelection")
    Call Application.OnTime(Now + TimeValue("00:01:00"), "M_PDF")
End Sub

Sub Mosaic_PDF()
Dim File_Path As String
Dim File_Name As String
Dim ReportTic As String
Dim Rng As Range, cl As Range


    Set Rng = Worksheets("Set_up").Range("A2:A300")
    With Worksheets("Mosaic")
        For Each cl In Rng
            If cl <> "" Then
                Sheets("Mosaic").Range("G3") = cl
                With Worksheets("Mosaic")

                     Call Application.Run("RefreshStaticLinks")

                End With



                File_Path = "N:\DATA\EQTY\EQFUND\SI\Projects\Standard Reporting\PDF Reports\Mosaic Fundamental Positioning\"
                File_Name = "Fundamental Positioning Summary "
                ReportTic = Format(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Mosaic").Range("G3").Text)


                'Exports to pdf
                With ActiveWorkbook
                    With Sheets(Array("Mosaic")).Select
                    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                    Filename:=File_Path & File_Name & ReportTic & ".pdf", _
                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                    OpenAfterPublish:=True

                    End With
                End With

            End If
        Next cl
    End With



End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to insert some kind of delay until the Bloomberg code is done.  Maybe try adding in a loop with `DoEvents`

Comment: It would be more robust to use the COM API, download the data directly from VBA and paste it in the sheet. The only alternative, using your current setup, is to run some code every N seconds, check if there are some N/A left, in which case keep waiting. Once there is not N/A left, run the rest of the code.

Comment: Maybe you should get away from Excel, and get into R or Python.  Then, all of these things are totally free, and 100% more reliable...

https://www.quantmod.com/examples/intro/.
https://www.quantmod.com/gallery/